# Codeigniter library Loader fail when more than one

Tags: php, codeigniter, loader

I am trying to use Codeigniter Loader to load library

```
$this->load->library();
```

and it will fail when I load more than one.

`application\controllers\news.php`

```
<?php

class News extends CI_Controller {

    public function aa() {
        echo 'this is aa.<br>';
        $this->load->library('bb');
        $this->load->library('cc');   
        $this->bb->call();  // This work fine.
        $this->cc->call();  // This will show php error.
    }

}

?>
```

`application\libraries\Bb.php`

```
<?

class Bb extends CI_Controller {

    public function __construct(){
        parent::__construct();
        echo 'bb constructed.<br>';
    }

    public function call(){
        echo 'bb function called.<br>';
    }


}
```

?>

`application\libraries\Cc.php`

```
<?  

class Cc extends CI_Controller {

    public function __construct(){
        parent::__construct();
        echo 'cc constructed.<br>';
    }

    public function call(){
        echo 'cc function called.<br>';
    }
}

?>
```

And here's some screen cap :

[image]

Codeigniter version : 2.2.0

PHP version : 5.2.6

Answer (score 0):

in your own libraries you dont need to extend to your controller class, so you can change your own libraries like these :

```
  <?php
  class Bb  {
    function call()
    {
    return 'Bb function called.<br>';
    }
  }
  ?>
```

and your Cc library :

```
  <?php
  class Cc  {
    function call()
    {
    return 'Cc function called.<br>';
    }
  }
  ?>
```

in controller you can easily :

```
  echo $this->bb->call();
  echo $this->cc->call();exit;
```

or every thing else depend on your library functions.

Comment: so does it means I can't load a controller class if i am not using HMVC extensions ? or is it not a good practices for using more than one controller in my app ?

Comment: Why would you use more then 1 controller in your app? to extend the functionality of your app (like users, languages, etc), use libraries. And you can load the current controller in your [library](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/general/creating_libraries.html) by using a reference, like [this](http://pastebin.com/g9fMiTUx).

Comment: maybe i am new to MCV, I was thinking to hava main Controller, which will works with other component controller in my web site, like the Search input, Shopping Chart. or may be even a controller for MainMenu, and a controller for ad banners.